# BNF parentheses and pipe

Tags: yacc

In Backus–Naur Form would:

```
print_stmt : "print" (string | expr)+
```

match to:

```
print string

print expr
```

or

```
print (string)

print (expr)
```

I'm not sure whether the parentheses have to be there or not.

Comment: This is not Badkus-Naur Form. It is the notation for *yacc(1)*. [tag:lex] has nothing to do with it either.

Answer (score 0):

It would match either of the first two options, and a number of other possibilities.

In this dialect of BNF, it appears that the parentheses are metacharacters.  The `+` probably means 'one or more' of the previous units, but if the `)` was repeated one or more times, it would be a very unusual language. If the `+` was absent, then either interpretation would be reasonable and I couldn't give as confident an answer; you would have to go back and find the specification for the dialect of BNF you're interpreting.

Because of the `+`, this should also be valid:

```
print string string expr string
```